# Encoding error running `activate` of a venv

Tags: windows, encoding, python-venv

I created a virtual environment with `python -m myvirtualenv`.

Now I want to activate it: 

`$ cd \ENV\myvirtualenv\Scripts
$ activate
wrong parameter - 850
$(myvirtualenv)`

Oddly enough, when I deactivate and then activate again, the error msg changes to "wrong parameter - 65001" and does not change after that.

Except for the error everything seems to be working fine.

This is a problem on win7, python 3.7, occuring both on the default windows shell and Cmder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in python (https://bugs.python.org/issue34144).
There is even a pull request waiting for review (https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8321).

The activate script first should do the following:

1. Read current code page (e.g. 850)
2. Change code page to 65001
3. Do the actual work
4. Change code page back

Due to the bug the current code page (e.g. 850) is parsed incorrectly due to a trailing `.` and can't be set back in the last step. This means in the second run it is still 65001.

Comment: Why does this raise an error in the second run then? The code page is 65001, which should not resolve in an error for pyenv, should it?

Comment: It also parses the 65001 code page incorrectly and and can't set the codepage back (the script always does step 4).